# What are the first/most basic cyber security precautions which should be implemented for an e-commerce website?

Tags: security, backend

I am new to web development, and particularly for the back end, I was wondering what are the first basic precautions should be implemented to ensure cybersecurity to avoid any exploits which could leak user data or credential for example.

Comment: Whole books or even university degrees cover this topic. It's *way* too broad for an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure you are following the CIA model:

1. Confidentiality:  Refers to access control of information to ensure that those who should not have access are kept out. This can be done with passwords, usernames, and other access control components.
2. Integrity: Ensures that the information end-users receive is accurate and unaltered by anyone other than the site owner. This is often done with encryption, such as Secure Socket Layer (SSL) certificates which ensure that data in transit is encrypted.
3. Availability: Ensures information can be accessed when needed.

Some other tips would be :

1. Use SSL certificate.
2. Take precautions when accepting file uploads through your site.(Incase if you have)
3. Use CSP (To prevent against Cross-site scripting)
4. Set permissions that controls who can read, write, and execute any given file or folder of your website.
5. Limit Login Attempts and temporarily lock out IP Addresses that make several failed attempts to get inside.
6. Keep scripts up-to-date.
7. Maintain multilayer security and keep backup.
8. And please take care of your Database, how you create and link it.
9. Lastly, show the beta version of your website to someone with good experience to look for any loopholes before your website goes live.